# how to disable specific warning when -Wall is enabled

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, compilation

I have used `-Wall -Werror` in my Makefile but I want to disable following specific type of warning :

```
 warning: '_wrap_delete_DMXTSFILTER' defined but not used
```

How shoud I do that?

Comment: Would not the correct way of doing this be to only `#define` it if it is going to be used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hide "defined but not used" warnings in GCC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386220/how-can-i-hide-defined-but-not-used-warnings-in-gcc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386220/hide-defined-but-not-used-warning-with-gcc/610141#610141)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's unused variable:

```
-Wno-unused-variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Finnaly, I used this trick 
`__attribute__((unused))`. The advantage is I could apply it to individual functions / variables instead of the whole source file which the `-Wno-unsed-xxxxx` will apply on.