# How can I disable -Wc++0x-compat when using -Wall?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, compiler-warnings

The `-Wall` flag in g++ includes the flag `-Wc++0x-compat`, which checks for all sorts of problems that may (will) appear if the code is compiled against the new c++11 standard.  But I'd like to disable that warning so that current warnings are not lost in the barrage of compatibility warnings.  I haven't found anything useful in the man page, nor with Google.  There doesn't seem to be a disabling flag like there is for e.g. [`-Wunused-variable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605519/how-to-disable-specific-warning-when-wall-is-enabled).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you fix your code so that it would be C++11 compliant, and still be valid C++03 code?

Comment: `-Wno-c++0x-compat`. This pattern is valid for all warning flags.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's not my code (it's Chromium if you're wondering), and it is c++11 compliant, but uses preprocessing to only use the c++11 features once they're available.

Comment: For reference: Looking at the man page, I noticed the option is called `-Wc++11-compat` ("11" instead of "0x") from GCC 4.7.0 onwards. So I guess it's disabled as `-Wno-c++11-compat` there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`-Wno-c++0x-compat`​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I thought I'd tried that but I seem to have missed the hyphen after the 'no'.  Thanks