# How do I use -Wall option on gcc/g++ and turn off the multi line comments warnings?

Tags: gcc, warnings

Like the title, how do I use -Wall option on gcc/g++ and turn off the multi-line comments warnings?

The comment looks like that:

```
// Comment starts here \
// and end here (the // at the beginning is not necessary)
```

Comment: Do you mean `//` rather than `\\`?

Comment: yes, I think the programmer idea was to create some sort of box with `// code \\ ` but the amount of `/` and `\ ` isn't uniform in the code... terrible idea

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use /* .. */ for the multiline comment.

```
    /* foo bar comment
       lala blah
    */
```

Edit:

I found a solution in another post here: [How can I hide "defined but not used" warnings in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386220/how-can-i-hide-defined-but-not-used-warnings-in-gcc)

If you add the option `-Wno-comment`, the warning is gone.

```
    gcc -Wall -Wno-comment test.c -o test
```

It's also explained here:  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: This is not my code, it has about 10 k line's, and it is mostly commented this way

Comment: @RSFalcon7: My condolences; that's a horribly bad commenting style. Note that if there's a space following the backslash, the backslash won't (necessarily) be recognized as a line continuation. Any chance you can fix the code?

Comment: @KeithThompson I know and I totally agree with you, this part wasn't my responsibility even if lost a few day to fix this it would be a totally waste of time since it would be dropped in the merge

Comment: @RSFalcon7: Since you're here, you might want to read the comment I posted on the question and fix the syntax in the code sample. And the code is *someone's* responsibility; consider talking to someone who can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash continuation induces the warning; it is not necessary if you start the next line with a comment start.

Remove the backslash continuation and replace the backslashes at the start of the line with `//` (as written, it is not a comment at all) and you should quell the warnings.

You can also write:

```
/\
\
* A regular C89 comment with trigraphs for good measure.
*??/
??/
/
```

and anyone who presented that code to me for review would be sent back to fix it immediately (but pity the poor compiler writer who has to handle such nonsense correctly!).

As to how to fix it, if (as is mentioned in a comment), it is prevalent then you can see whether your version of GCC will support `-Wno-comment` to suppress warnings about multiline comments.  That is probably simplest.  Failing that, you have to decide whether you can risk using a heuristic parser to fix the problem:

```
sed -e 's%\(//.*\)\\$%\1%' -i.bak *.c
```

(assuming GNU `sed` for the `-i.bak` option).  This removes the trailing backslash from any such comment.  The main place where I could see this causing trouble is in a macro definition such as:

```
#define MACRO(c,d) { (c) = (d) + 1; }  // Comment here \
                                          more comment here
```

It's an inane macro, but because there is no comment-start on the second line of the comment, the heuristic substitution in the `sed` script would give you a syntactically invalid program (unless you just so happened to have macros such that 'more comment here' expands to valid code, which is pretty unlikely).

If the heuristic mechanism won't work, then maybe you need a full C comment stripper.  If you can't find one on the Internet somewhere, I have such a program (and its test files include comments such as the gruesome one shown above) — see my profile.

Answer (score 1):

The GCC warnings are documented here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Specifically, you're looking for:

> -Wcomment
>
> > Warn whenever a comment-start sequence `/*' appears in a`/*' comment, or whenever a Backslash-Newline appears in a `//' comment. This warning is enabled by -Wall.

So to turn that warning off, you should be able to use `-Wno-comment`.