# What is a casted parameter statement in C?

Tags: c

in the following function

```
int f (some_struct* p)
{
    (void) p;
    /* something else */
    return 0;
}
```

what does the statement

```
(void) p;
```

mean?

Answer (score 12):

The statement does nothing at runtime, and results in no machine code.

It suppresses a compiler warning that `p` is unused in the body of the function.  This is a portable and safe way to suppress this warning across a variety of different compilers, including GCC, Clang, and Visual C++.

Comment: does this mean "void" is the only type can be put there?

Comment: If you put a different type there, some compilers will generate a "statement with no effect" warning.  If you put `void` there, you are communicating both to the compiler and to humans reading the code that you know that the statement has no effect, and you are okay with that.  Also, any type can be cast to `void` in C (in C++, the story is different).

Answer (score 2):

“Cast to `void`” is a C language idiom that, by convention, suppresses compiler and `lint` warnings about unused variables or return values.

In this case, as Dietrich Epp correctly points out, it tells the compiler that you know that you're not using the argument `p`, and not to give you “unused argument” warnings about it.

The other use of this idiom, casting the return value of a function to `void`, is the traditional way of telling `lint` or, more importantly, other programmers that you'd made a conscious decision not to bother checking the return value of a function. For example:

```
(void)printf("foo")
```

Would mean “I know `printf()` returns a value, and I should really check it, but I've decided not to bother”.

Answer (score 0):

It's used to avoid the warning of unused function parameter. It simply gets discarded, does nothing except that the expression has a side effect.

> **C11 §6.3.2.2 void**
>
> The (nonexistent) value of a void expression (an expression that has type void) shall not
> be used in any way, and implicit or explicit conversions (except to void) shall not be
> applied to such an expression. **If an expression of any other type is evaluated as a void
> expression, its value or designator is discarded. (A void expression is evaluated for its
> side effects.)**

Another way to avoid the warning of unused function parameter is:

```
p = p;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `void` tells the compiler or lint do not give warning. If there are a variable never be used, compiler or lint will suggestion you delete it.

If you do not want to delete it, you can use void. Like the link : [How can I hide "defined but not used" warnings in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386220/how-can-i-hide-defined-but-not-used-warnings-in-gcc)